# ¿Como puedo saber cuantos creditos le falta a un estudiante para graduarse?

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
select DISTINCT Kardex.id_Estudiante,Kardex.id_Materia,Kardex.Creditos_Aprobados from Kardex
inner join Carrera
on Kardex.id_Kardex = Carrera.id_Carrera
where Kardex.Creditos_Aprobados <> Carrera.Total_Creditos;
```

¿Como puedo hacer la resta de Carrera.Total_Creditos y Kardex.Creditos_Aprobados para saber la cantidad de créditos que le falta para terminar la carrera? ¿Alguna recomendación por favor?

Comment: Restando los dos campos no sirve?

Comment: No lo habia logrado, un compañero ya me dio una idea. Muchas gracias amigo, es que soy nuevo en el mundo de las BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resta el total de créditos a la cantidad de créditos aprobados.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
        Kardex.id_Estudiante,
        Kardex.id_Materia,
        (Carrera.Total_Creditos - Kardex.Creditos_Aprobados) as 'Creditos faltantes'
FROM Kardex
INNER JOIN Carrera
    ON Kardex.id_Kardex = Carrera.id_Carrera
WHERE 
    Kardex.Creditos_Aprobados <> Carrera.Total_Creditos;
```

Comment: Excelente, justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias amigo, me fue sumamente útil.